# Maven java version per module

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

Want to add java 7 compiled module to existing java 6 compiled maven project.

Anyone knows whether this project structure is supported by:

1) Maven
2) Intellij Idea
3) Eclipse

Any other thoughts why should (or should not) this be done.

Comment: Do you mean a dependency or a sub module of a multi-module build ?

Comment: A submodule of a multi-module project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is supported. For each module, in Maven you need to specify the proper compiler source and target versions. When you import it in IntelliJ it will know. I'm sure Eclipse will figure it out as well.